# is letter “y” derived from “ij”?

Tags: language-evolution, silent-letters

It is my intuition, that the origin of the letter *y* comes from *ij* based on the usage in Dutch where it very closely resembles *ij* in both sound and shape. I would go so far as to say it looks like a contraction.

I am particularly interested in this right now, as a company has translated a foreign name into English, and included *iy* in the name – which strikes me as unusual. If I were transliterating their name, *Bafiya* seems wrong – and I feel it is better as *Bafya* or *Bafia*.

It is hard to justify my opinion, so I was curious about the usage of *iy*. I can not think of any words that contain *iy* in them. Are there any?

Comment: Words with *ij* in them? Sure, plenty: *bijou, feijoa, gaijin, hijacker, marijuana, Ouija, skijamas*.  As you see, all are either foreign or compounds. And the reason it needs to be *Bafiya* instead of *Bafia* is because otherwise you won’t get the “bike” vowel, only the “speak” vowel, and you might get the stress wrong, too.

Comment: Note that the character "j" is a much later addition to Latin-derived alphabets than "y".

Comment: @tchrist *Bafiya* will still be pronounced with the 'speak' sound by those new to that word. In that case, *Bafaia* is what you'll need for the 'bike' sound.

Comment: @Kris Nope, most native speakers will think that that is like *layer* not like *fire*.

Comment: I don’t know about Dutch but I can assure you that “ÿ” doesn’t exist in German at all. German only knows three umlauts, “ä”, “ö” and “ü”. You’ll also occasionally find a trema ( ¨ ) on other letters such as in “Citroën” or “Moët” but those are not German words.

Comment: When I see "Bafiya", I say "Bah-fee-ya".  When I see "Bafia" or "Bafya", I (usually) say "Baf-yah".  I have no idea which is correct, but I'd need to see "Bafaia" or (more normal for English) "Bafaya" to pronounce it that third way; @Kris is that last one the _real_ correct pronunciation?

Comment: @tchrist I was asking for words with 'iy' not 'ij'. As to me, it seems almost equivalent to 'iij' which seems to have too many consecutive i to be an English word.

Comment: @BillyMoon That is even harder. There’s *teriyaki*, and the colloquial *hiya*. After that are loanwords I wouldn’t expect anyone to know.

Comment: @tchrist Mandarin Teriyaki Pronunciation: http://www.pronouncehow.com/english/mandarin-teriyaki_pronunciation ; \ˌter-ē-ˈyä-kē\ (Merriam-Webster) ter-uh-yah-kee (dictionary.reference.com); BrE  ˌterɪˈjɑːki BrE ˌterɪˈjæki NAmE ˌterɪˈjɑːki (OxfordLearnersDictionaries);

Comment: Kris Please cite pronunciations only in IPA. The rest are useless. Certainly the American pronunciation is `/ˌterɪˈjɑːki/`.  I do not know what your point is, however.

Comment: @Izkata There is no way we can define "the real correct pronunciation" -- "I love Draco actor Jay Laga'aia, but how do you pronouce it? Thanks to Stacey who tells me it is LAH - GUYE - AH" (http://www.xenaville.com/pronun.html) "Oh, and for anyone who is wondering, you pronounce his last name “Lah-guy-ah”." (http://www.theonering.net/torwp/category/tornarchive/page/895/)

Comment: @tchrist We don't always find IPA on all sources. I have given the urls some of which have links to audio. The word has no standard pronunciation.

Comment: @Kris *“The word has no standard pronunciation”*? Surely you jest! The OED gives only `/tɛrɪˈjɑːkɪ/`, which in my experience is indeed its standard pronunciation. To assert otherwise seems misguided at best. Also, if you don’t have IPA, please do not bother. It is not reasonable on an international forum to expect people to learn a new set of non-standard, proprietary hieroglyphics for each utterance. **It is for this reason that IPA was invented: it is *the* international standard.**

Comment: @sumelic also it is confusing. Is it about letter forms, or is it about spelling? also is it about Dutch borrowings into English, or simply about a change within English?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/BattleOfRidgefield2.png All the towns spelled with an ij ending now have a "y". Danbury, Rye, bay, etc.
Odd that County is spelled with a y ending.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mostly no, but also yes.

In most languages, *y* is from the Greek letter upsilon, [as pointed out by “Matt Эллен”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93112/14073).

The *ij* digraph from Dutch, though, was originally *ii* with a lengthened second *i* to distinguish it in handwriting from *u*.

However, from *ij* came the Afrikaans *y*. Quoth [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29#History):

> *IJ* probably developed out of *ii*, representing a long [iː] sound (which it still does in some occasions, such as in the word *bijzonder* and in several Dutch dialects). In the Middle Ages, the *i* was written without a dot in handwriting, and the combination *ıı* was often confused with *u*. Therefore, the second *i* was elongated. Later, the dots were added, albeit not in Afrikaans, a language that has its roots in Dutch. In this language the *y* is used instead.

So this is an example of a yes to your question, but it probably only happened because the letter *y* already existed.

Finally, off the top of my head, words containing *iy* are usually transliterations from Russian or other Cyrillic languages, e.g., *[Dmitriy Karpov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitriy_Karpov)* or *[Nataliya Gotsiy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nataliya_Gotsiy)*.

Comment: An aside: if the text speak of my other half is anything to go by, the Dutch ij may be shifting towards y again.  Or maybe it's just a character-/effort-saving measure.

Comment: +1 transliteration from Cyrillic ... You may see transliteration iĭ but nowadays more likely iy.

Comment: It's also common in Arabic with the suffix -ya, which can be after i, and names such as Iyad and Ziyad.

Answer (score 13):

No. The letter *Y* comes from the Greek letter [upsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon), via the Latin alphabet.

For more information see [the wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y).

Comment: "The oldest direct ancestor of English letter Y was the Semitic letter waw, from which also come F, U, V, and W. ... The Greek and Latin alphabets developed from the Phoenician form of this early alphabet."

Comment: Thanks, @Kris, I did read that, but that's irrelevant to the question as the **English** letter came from the **Greek**, not the Phoenician, which is where the Greek came from. I wasn't looking to explain where the Greek letter came from.

Comment: It came "via the Latin alphabet" so should it then be Latin, not Greek via Latin?

Comment: @Kris if you read the Wikipedia article you can see that upsilon is not a Latin letter, it is used in Latin. It is still Greek there.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y#History). The letter Y hails back to the times of Phoenicians, pre-dating the Greeks.

Comment: Only in the trivial sense that nearly all our letters date back to the Phoenicians, via the Greeks, Etruscans and Romans.

Comment: Not all letters descended from the Phoenicians. The letter is amongst those that did and by inference did not originate from germanic ij.

Comment: Well, you can make a case that J, V, W and G were not, in that they were all derived from other letters which were. That seems to make "descent from Phoenician" pretty much the default condition for a letter.